# Using onKeyup() to validate field based on input length - Jquery Form validation engine by posAbsolute

Tags: jquery, forms, passwords, onkeyup, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jQuery validation engine by posAbsolute and i've come across a problem I just can't figure out the solution to. 
In the validation engine plugin each field validates onBlur by default. The scenario I have is a password input field into which at least four characters must be entered before the form will validate it on clicking submit. Right now, if i enter less than 4 characters, and click away the error div appears above the input field, however, I want the error div to hide when the user comes back and types at least 4 characters, and to otherwise remain.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="register-form span5">       
<form method="post" form id="formID" class="formular form-horizontal" action="/account/registerguest">
<div class="row-fluid">
<fieldset class="span4">    
<label for="password">Password:</label> 
<input data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[password]]" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
</fieldset> 
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

And the jquery:

```
(function($){
$.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function(){
};
$.validationEngineLanguage = {
    newLang: function(){
        $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {
            "required": { 
                "regex": "none",
                // "alertText": "* This field is required",                  
            },                    

            "password": {
                "regex": /(?=^.{4,}$)/,
                "alertText": "*Enter at least 4 characters"
            },             

        };

    }
};

$.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();    
})(jQuery);

    $("#formID").validationEngine();

function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options){
    if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
        // this allows to use i18 for the error msgs
        return options.allrules;
    }
}
```

And then of course the validation engine: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

I would be very thankful for any help regarding this. I hope i've given enough info. I so far haven't found the question of replacing onBlur validation in this plugin with onKeyup anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more poking around I found the solution. Replace 'blur' in the plugin.js file with 'keyup'.

> // LEAK GLOBAL OPTIONS
>       $.validationEngine= {fieldIdCounter: 0,defaults:{

```
    // Name of the event triggering field validation
    validationEventTrigger: "keyup",
    // Automatically scroll viewport to the first error
    scroll: false,
    // Focus on the first input
    focusFirstField:true,
    // Show prompts, set to false to disable prompts
    showPrompts: true,
```